# What are assertions or NSAssert good for in practice?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I wonder if it's a good habit to use NSAssert all over the place? What would be the benefit of doing that? In which situations is it a good idea to use it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Broad use of `NSAssert()` will not turn ObjC into Eiffel, but it's still a fairly good practice as long as you keep in mind how it's actually implemented and what it's doing. Things to keep in mind about `NSAssert()`:

Xcode does not turn off `NSAssert()` in Release mode by default. You have to remember to add `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` to `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` in you xcconfig. (You are [using xcconfigs](http://robnapier.net/blog/build-system-1-build-panel-360), right?) A common issue is to assert non-nil in cases where nil will quietly work; this can mean field crashes for things that could have gracefully recovered. This is unrelated to the `NDEBUG` macro used by `assert()`, and you have to remember to define both if your code includes both types of assertions.

If you compile out `NSAssert()` in Release mode, then you get no indication where a problem happened when customers send you their logs. I personally wrap `NSAssert()` in my own macros that always log, even in Release mode.

`NSAssert()` often forces duplicated logic. Consider the case of testing a C++ pointer for NULL. You use `NSAssert()`, but you *still* need to use a simple `if()` test as well to avoid crashing in the field. This kind of duplicated code can become the source of bugs, and I have seen code that fails due to assertions that are no longer valid. (Luckily this is generally in Debug mode!) I have debated a lot how to create a macro that would combine the assertion and `if()`, but it's hard to do without being fragile or making the code hard to understand.

Because of the last issue, I typically put "`NSAssert(NO, ...)`" in an `else{}` clause rather than performing assertion at the top of the method. This is not ideal because it moves the contract away from the method signature (thus reducing its documentary benefit), but it is the most effective approach I've found in practice.

Comment: I don't see why you would end up with duplicate code. If the assertion fails, your code has no obligation to save itself from a crash. In fact there is no point, because an assumption you have made has been broken, so there is no sane way to save the program from not crashing later, due to inconsistent state.

Comment: Your code always has an obligation to behave well for the user. While in some cases concern of data corruption means that crashing immediately is the only approach. But in many cases this is not true and recovering, showing an error or even doing nothing is preferable in Release vs crashing and leaving the user staring at Springboard with no information. I've seen enough incorrect assertions in production code to be very wary of preemptive crashing in Release in the absence of possible data corruption. Debug is a completely different situation, and I advocate crashing quickly.

Comment: A good app acknowledges that it has bugs and seeks to contain them. Just because I have a minor bug in the help system shouldn't mean that the entire game should crash just because technically the "program is now undefined." Every real program of any size involves quite a lot of undefined behavior. It's our responsibility to minimize that, but also to live within that and not crash every time something looks strange.

Comment: I guess we are just of different schools then. I belong to fail fast. IMHO an assert is for things you can not recover from. There is nothing you can do in code to fix it. So rather than screw up the users data in some way, you should crash as soon as possible. I mean crashes exist in the OS for a reason. Corrupt data, wrong calculations etc are worse than a crash.

Comment: We're from the same school, just different professional shops. You should absolutely crash rather than corrupt data. But many things that can and should be asserted on do not need to lead to any of those things. And as I said, crashing the entire app because someone sent a surprising parameter to the Help system's constructor is bad User Experience (which is why we're here, not proof of correctness). During development, I absolutely fail fast and crash. During release, I fail fast but never crash if data will be safe.

Comment: I agree that an assert is for things you cannot recover from, but the "you" in this case generally means "your method" or "your section of the program." Limiting assertions to things that then *entire* program could never recover from limits assertions to too small a set.

Comment: Just one more thing :D I am making a strong distinction between an assertion and an exception. Exceptions should always crash the program. Low level code (data structures especially) and user-data-impacting code should use exceptions to enforce that. Assertions, by design going back to assert(), are meant to be taken out in Release mode. They help you find programming errors, even if they could potentially be recovered from (at least in showing an error) in Release.

Comment: @RobNapier, can you provide us with an example (here, or elsewhere online) of an example of how you accomplish this: *"I personally wrap NSAssert() in my own macros that always log, even in Release mode."* I would appreciate the insight. since I see the value in this, but I am not sure how this is setup. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The major warning are side effects. If you write:

```
NSAssert([self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]!=nil,@"Something fails");
```

`popViewControllerAnimated:` will be executed in the debug version, but not in the release version that strips `NSAssert()`. This means that your release version will behave different to the debug version.

This problem disappears if you are careful enough:

```
UIViewController* vc = [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
NSAssert(vc!=nil,@"Something fails");
```

Answer (score 7):

Debugging. Whenever you write code, you're almost always making assumptions. Assumptions about the state of the environment, the values of your parameters, your local variables and fields, etc. Oftentimes, these assumptions are just wrong (an old collegue gave me a good maxim, that "Assumption is the mother of all fsckups").

Assertions exist to validate your assumptions, at the point you make them. You have a method

```
void foo(int x)
{
   …
}
```

that you know and have documented only works for x > 5? Assert it!

Assertions live alongside unit testing and formal methods as part of good coding practice. Whilst some might think comprehensive unit tests ensure assertions are redundant, it's not the case. For example, you may have an assumption to a method that, say, employees are always over 16 and under 100 years old - but that the code, at the moment, doesn't require this. Unit tests that pass those parameters will succeed, but later when you need to use your assumption, you'll have code everywhere that passed the tests, but is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend this article

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-05-03-proper-use-of-asserts.html

And as the article states it is often good to use a assert-mechanism which is not NSAssert. For example:

https://github.com/hfossli/AGAssert