# Reading custom NSObject from NSObject property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, nsobject

I have a custom NSObject Class, lets call in People, and a Class from the CloudMade RMMarker.h called RMMarker. The RMMarker class has a property called data which is a NSObject. I know set the data by doing this:

```
People *aPeople = [[People alloc] init];   
marker.data = aPeople;
```

How can I read the data which is stored in data? All I know is its not

```
People *aPeople = [[People alloc] init];
aPeople = marker.data;
```

What is the right way to do so?

Thanks
Philip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know that `marker.data` is of type `People *`, you can simply cast it to the correct type:

```
People *aPeople = (People *)marker.data;
```

Note that this will only work properly if `marker.data` is actually a `People *` object (or one of its subclasses). To be sure, you can add an [assertion test](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSAssert):

```
People *aPeople = (People *)marker.data;
NSAssert([aPeople isKindOfClass:[People class]], "oops! Wrong type!");
```

For important details regarding the use of [NSAssert()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSAssert), please read: [What are assertions or NSAssert good for in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374474/what-are-assertions-or-nsassert-good-for-in-practice)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from the RMMarker source the data ivar will just retain your People object. So if you want to reference the People object later just do:

```
 People *aPeople = (People *)marker.data;
```